# High-dimensional gaussian averages

Tags: python, math, statistics, scientific-computing

Is there a way to precisely and efficiently calculate averages with an arbitrarily-dimensional gaussian distribution (say, in Python)? How difficult is this task computationally? Are there any existing solutions for this?

[image: Integral]

Comment: If this is just a general mathematical question, this is better for Stack Exchange's math site (https://math.stackexchange.com) otherwise, I think it's fair to ask what research you've done and code you tried.

Comment: Can you say of what sort of functions f you need the averages?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Monte Carlo Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) this is a technique for integration that is supposed to be especially good for high dimensional cases.